# Git Hook Custom Command for Each File Changed Before Push

Tags: git, githooks

I'm trying to run a custom command on every file changed before a push. I'm looking over the pre-push sample:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/87c86dd14abe8db7d00b0df5661ef8cf147a72a3/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample

but I can't figure out how to iterate over commits. I've looked at git log but I can't tell how to distinguish commits since the last push.

**How can I iterate over each file change before a git push?**

Answer (score 2):

Taking the sample code, and adding the iteration...

```
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    ... various checks for $z40 etc...
    for commit in $(git rev-list --abbrev-commit $remote_sha..$local_sha)
    do
       <your checks on $commit here>
    done
done
```